# 2nd column is tucking below the 1st column, what are common causes of this?

Tags: html, css

My HTML is too eleborate to post here.

I have a 2 column layout, the 1st column is 160px and the 2nd column is much bigger.

For some reason the 2nd column is tucking below the 1st column.

What are common causes for this?

**Update**

What I want is this:

Column#1  Column#2

What is displaying (**firefox is ok, IE6 is causing the problem**):

Column#1
Column#2

**Update**

The 2nd column is wrapped in a

And the blueprintcss has this:

```
.container:after {content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
```

So I guess it is the **clear:both** ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "tucking"? Do you mean column 2 fills up the parent container when column 1 ends?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both columns are floated (left), the second column will tuck underneath the first one if:

- It has `clear:left;` assigned to it
- it’s too wide for the available space

If the problem is occurring in IE 6, it might be the [IE 6 3-pixel gap](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/threepxtest.html) bug.

(We’d probably have a better chance of helping you if you put some actual code in the post. At the moment we’re guessing.)

**Update**

I don’t think it’s `clear: both;` — that rule won’t be affecting IE 6, as it doesn’t support the `:after` pseudo-selector. Here’s a test page demonstrating it:

http://www.pauldwaite.me.uk/testy.html

Comment: Is there a way to override the clearleft on it?  It is using blueprintcss which may have that by default.

Comment: If your second column is wrapped in div.container, no, I’m afraid not. div.container will be clearing the first column (i.e. tucking below it), and will take its contents (i.e. your second column) with it.

Comment: Wait, sorry, I’m talking nonsense. The CSS you posted from BluePrint won’t be causing IE6 issues, as it won’t work in IE 6 (IE 6 doesn’t support the `:after` pseudo-class).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Paul's 2 reasons, you have to keep in mind IE6 "double margin" bug.

In IE6, `float` property doubles margin accordingly (`float: left;` affects `margin-left` and vice versa).